# How to translate a OOP class diagram to a unity game/unity code

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, oop, scripting

Iv'e been coding games in c#, visual studio using OOP. Before starting a project i've always liked to draw up a class diagram to get an idea of how everything, the classes and objects are going to be connected.

And now after transitioning to Unity and scripting, i'm a bit confused to how i'm supposed to organize my scripts and connect them and the GameObjects. So i've come to understand that Unity consists of GameObjects in the scene, which consists of components, which a script is.

And lastly, i'm now starting a project on a 3D Tower Defense game and have drawn a class diagram as i would have for a Visual Studio game. How do i translate this to GameObjects, components and scripts in unity, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, to transition from the diagram to a Unity game object, you need to create a script for the class you want. By default all classes inherit from MonoBehaviour, which is a basic class unity provides with some basic variables and methods you will use often such as `gameObject` (a reference to the current GO) or `GetComponent<T>()` which returns a component of type `T` from the gameobject it runs on.

To connect a script to a game object just drag and drop it on the object in the hierarchy or the inspector (you can also add components via scripts!)
But for a script to run it must be attached to a game object.

You can read Unity's documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/index.html)
and watch tutorials on YouTube like on [this](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYbK_tjZ2OrIZFBvU6CCMiA) channel

Basically anything you want to do as a beginner in Unity, someone already made a tutorial on it. Good luck!